# How to use volatile multimap iterator?

Tags: c++

I need to use a volatile multimap iterator, but iterator's operators (such as ++) doesn't work when it is defined as volatile...

First of all: why do I need a volatile iterator (and NOT a mutable one)?

I write an utility class (Echeancier) which must schedule a list of deadlines (Echeance), ordered by date.
All the deadlines are stored in a multimap whose key is the deadline's date (_echeancesParDate).

Each deadline is managed successively, with only one linux timer: 
- when timer expires, it generates a signal; 
- signal's handler handles the event associated to the deadline and then, shall restart the timer for the next deadline.

> So I need to use typeListeEcheancesParDate::iterator _comingEcheance in a signal handler.

On the other hand, class Echeancier also defines a function to create new deadlines (ajouterEcheance()).
This function may update _comingEcheance.

> That's why I need to define _comingEcheance as volatile.

NB: for the moment, I put the atomic access aspect aside.

My source code (partial):

```
    class Echeancier
    {

      private:
        typedef std::multimap<Echeance::typeDateEcheance,   Echeance*> typeListeEcheancesParDate;

        typeListeEcheancesParDate _echeancesParDate;

        typeListeEcheancesParDate::iterator volatile _comingEcheance;

        void handlerEcheance(Echeance::typeEvenementEcheance eventEcheance);

        AsyncTimer<Echeancier>* _timer;
        int _numSignalTimer;

      protected:
        Echeancier(int signalEcheance);
        ~Echeancier();

        virtual void traiterEvenement(Echeance::typeEvenementEcheance eventEcheance) = 0;

        int ajouterEcheance(Echeance::typeDateEcheance date,
                    Echeance::typeEvenementEcheance evenement,
                    Echeance::typeIdentifiantEcheance & idEcheance);
        int supprimerEcheance(Echeance::typeIdentifiantEcheance idEcheance);
    }
```

The only idea I have is to overload multimap iterator ++ operator, to make it works with volatile modifier...
But I don't know how to do this... any idea for my problem?
Thanks

Comment: To me `volatile` for anything other than hardware registers is a "bad smell"... Why is the code using `volatile` in the first place? Surely if some other thread can manipulate them, you need proper locks to prevent another thread from messing up the current threads work by modifying the list... And with proper locks, `volatile` isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I do not use this code in a multithread context; I need a volatile variable because this iterator is modified in a signal handler function; this handler function may be called asynchronously, at any point in the program, unpredictably: it's an agent external to main program (like an hardware interrupt would be).

Answer (score 1):

So, I made a comment saying that `volatile` is a bad smell in multithreaded contexts, and I stand by that.

It is also a bad smell to manipulate your data in a signal handler. Using locks also don't work in signal handlers, since there is no other thread to unlock a lock held by the main thread of the program.

I'd argue that you need to rethink your whole design, and use two threads [one of which may be controlled by a timer signal handler, and have a high priority]. The point is that manipulating your iterator and the data the iterator points at, will have to be dealt with atomically, and just marking something `volatile` does not solve that - `volatile` just means that the compiler has to "do exactly what the code says to do" - but it doesn't mean that your data itself is safe.